Non-finite expectation values in quantum mechanics
In textbook quantum mechanics, one deals with expectation values of the form
$$\langle O \rangle = \text{tr}(\rho O)$$
where $\rho$ is assumed to be trace-class (in particular, $\text{tr}\rho = 1$). Hence, $\rho O$ is also trace-class and the right hand side is finite. However, isn't this constraint too restrictive? In real life, certain common distributions (e.g. power law distributions) do not have certain finite moments. So, my question is: Can we extend the framework of quantum mechanics to model observables that do not have certain finite moments?

This question is similar to: Do states with infinite average energy make sense?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also the link(s) therein.

BTW: Why do you say the RHS is finite? In general, $\rho O$ is not of trace-class without further specifications.

Don't worry, if you ever find some infinity, ask a QFT theorist  to help you make it finite.
